# yum update returns conflicts with postgresql

Tags: centos, postgresql

`cat /etc/centos-release`
`CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011`

`yum update` returns errors as seen below, some conflicts with postgresql 12 installation.

Following this guide: [Install psql 12 on Centos8](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-centos-8) I installed postgres 12.

As root user:

```
dnf module list postgresql
dnf module enable postgresql:12
dnf install postgresql-server
postgresql-setup --initdb
systemctl start postgresql
systemctl enable postgresql
```

That was a a while ago, Now when I try to `yum update` or `dnf update` I get:

```
Error: 
 Problem 1: cannot install the best update candidate for package libpq-devel-12.4-1.el8_2.x86_64
  - package postgresql13-devel-13.1-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql13(x86-64) = 13.1-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.5-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql11-devel-11.10-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql11(x86-64) = 11.10-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql10-devel-10.15-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql10(x86-64) = 10.15-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql13-13.1-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql11-11.10-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql10-10.15-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
 Problem 2: problem with installed package libpq-devel-12.4-1.el8_2.x86_64
  - package libpq-devel-12.4-1.el8_2.x86_64 requires libpq(x86-64) = 12.4-1.el8_2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package libpq5-13.0-10PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq provided by libpq-12.4-1.el8_2.x86_64
  - package postgresql13-devel-13.0-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql13(x86-64) = 13.0-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql13-devel-13.0-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql13(x86-64) = 13.0-2PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql13-devel-13.1-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql13(x86-64) = 13.1-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.3-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.3-4PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.3-5PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.3-5PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.4-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.4-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.4-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.4-4PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.5-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql11-devel-11.10-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql11(x86-64) = 11.10-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql11-devel-11.8-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql11(x86-64) = 11.8-2PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql11-devel-11.9-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql11(x86-64) = 11.9-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql11-devel-11.9-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql11(x86-64) = 11.9-4PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql10-devel-10.15-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql10(x86-64) = 10.15-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libpq-12.4-1.el8_2.x86_64
  - package postgresql13-13.0-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql13-13.0-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql13-13.1-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.3-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.3-5PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.4-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.4-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql11-11.10-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql11-11.8-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql11-11.9-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql11-11.9-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql10-10.15-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Tried
`dnf clean all`
`dnf --best update`
But didn't solve, any ideas?

**Some outputs:**

`dnf module list postgresql` output:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:36 ago on Tue 08 Dec 2020 18:22:50 IST.
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream
Name                            Stream                      Profiles                               Summary                                                
postgresql                      9.6                         client, server [d]                     PostgreSQL server and client module                    
postgresql                      10 [d]                      client, server [d]                     PostgreSQL server and client module                    
postgresql                      12 [e]                      client, server [d]                     PostgreSQL server and client module                    

Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled
```

`yum list --installed | grep postg`

```
Modular dependency problems:

 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBI:1.641:8010020191113222731:16b3ab4d-0.x86_64
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-IO-Socket-SSL:2.066:8030020200715230104:1e4bbb35-0.x86_64
 Problem 3: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-libwww-perl:6.34:8030020200716155257:b967a9a2-0.x86_64
postgresql.x86_64                             12.1-2.module_el8.1.0+273+979c16e6                @AppStream  
postgresql-contrib.x86_64                     12.1-2.module_el8.1.0+273+979c16e6                @AppStream  
postgresql-server.x86_64                      12.1-2.module_el8.1.0+273+979c16e6                @AppStream
```

`dnf update --nobest`

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:45 ago on Tue 08 Dec 2020 18:22:50 IST.
Dependencies resolved.

 Problem 1: cannot install the best update candidate for package libpq-devel-12.4-1.el8_2.x86_64
  - package postgresql13-devel-13.1-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql13(x86-64) = 13.1-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.5-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql11-devel-11.10-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql11(x86-64) = 11.10-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql10-devel-10.15-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql10(x86-64) = 10.15-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql13-13.1-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql11-11.10-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql10-10.15-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
 Problem 2: problem with installed package libpq-devel-12.4-1.el8_2.x86_64
  - package libpq-devel-12.4-1.el8_2.x86_64 requires libpq(x86-64) = 12.4-1.el8_2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package libpq5-13.0-10PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 obsoletes libpq provided by libpq-12.4-1.el8_2.x86_64
  - package postgresql13-devel-13.0-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql13(x86-64) = 13.0-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql13-devel-13.0-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql13(x86-64) = 13.0-2PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql13-devel-13.1-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql13(x86-64) = 13.1-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.3-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.3-4PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.3-5PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.3-5PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.4-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.4-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.4-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.4-4PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql12-devel-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql12(x86-64) = 12.5-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql11-devel-11.10-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql11(x86-64) = 11.10-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql11-devel-11.8-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql11(x86-64) = 11.8-2PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql11-devel-11.9-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql11(x86-64) = 11.9-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql11-devel-11.9-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql11(x86-64) = 11.9-4PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package postgresql10-devel-10.15-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql10(x86-64) = 10.15-1PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libpq-12.4-1.el8_2.x86_64
  - package postgresql13-13.0-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql13-13.0-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql13-13.1-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.3-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.3-5PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.4-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.4-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql12-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql11-11.10-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql11-11.8-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql11-11.9-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql11-11.9-4PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package postgresql10-10.15-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
==========================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                    Architecture                   Version                                   Repository                      Size
==========================================================================================================================================================
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 postgresql10-devel                         x86_64                         10.15-1PGDG.rhel8                         pgdg10                         2.1 M
 postgresql11-devel                         x86_64                         11.10-1PGDG.rhel8                         pgdg11                         2.1 M
 postgresql11-devel                         x86_64                         11.8-2PGDG.rhel8                          pgdg11                         2.1 M
 postgresql11-devel                         x86_64                         11.9-1PGDG.rhel8                          pgdg11                         2.1 M
 postgresql11-devel                         x86_64                         11.9-4PGDG.rhel8                          pgdg11                         2.1 M
 postgresql12-devel                         x86_64                         12.3-4PGDG.rhel8                          pgdg12                         2.2 M
 postgresql12-devel                         x86_64                         12.3-5PGDG.rhel8                          pgdg12                         2.2 M
 postgresql12-devel                         x86_64                         12.4-1PGDG.rhel8                          pgdg12                         2.2 M
 postgresql12-devel                         x86_64                         12.4-4PGDG.rhel8                          pgdg12                         2.2 M
 postgresql12-devel                         x86_64                         12.5-1PGDG.rhel8                          pgdg12                         2.2 M
 postgresql13-devel                         x86_64                         13.0-1PGDG.rhel8                          pgdg13                         2.3 M
 postgresql13-devel                         x86_64                         13.0-2PGDG.rhel8                          pgdg13                         2.3 M
 postgresql13-devel                         x86_64                         13.1-1PGDG.rhel8                          pgdg13                         2.3 M

Transaction Summary
==========================================================================================================================================================
Skip  13 Packages

Nothing to do.
Complete
```

`dnf repolist`

```
repo id                                                 repo name
appstream                                               CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream
baseos                                                  CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS
epel                                                    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
epel-modular                                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
extras                                                  CentOS Linux 8 - Extras
pgdg-common                                             PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64
pgdg10                                                  PostgreSQL 10 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64
pgdg11                                                  PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64
pgdg12                                                  PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64
pgdg13                                                  PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64
pgdg95                                                  PostgreSQL 9.5 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64
pgdg96                                                  PostgreSQL 9.6 for RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64
```

`dnf module list perl`

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:49:49 ago on Tue 08 Dec 2020 18:49:06 IST.
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream
Name                     Stream                       Profiles                                Summary                                                     
perl                     5.24                         common [d], minimal                     Practical Extraction and Report Language                    
perl                     5.26 [d]                     common [d], minimal                     Practical Extraction and Report Language                    
perl                     5.30                         common [d], minimal                     Practical Extraction and Report Language                    

Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled
```

`perl --version`

`This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3)...`

`dnf --disablerepo=pgdg\* update`

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:36:55 ago on Tue 08 Dec 2020 18:49:02 IST.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

So updating while disabling pgdg works.
Not sure how to proceed though.

Comment: What is the output of `dnf repolist`?  Does it contain the upstream repositories for `postgresql`?  If you want to install from RHEL repositories, you may need to disable any upstream `postgresql` repositories.  You also do not seem to have Perl 5.26 available which it looks like `postgresql` requires.  What is the output of `dnf module list perl`?

Comment: @GracefulRestart Updated question

Comment: You have many `postgresql` upstream versions enabled in your `dnf` repository.  You should probably double-check which repository you actually installed `postgresql` from.  If you have packages from those repositories, `dnf` will attempt to upgrade them and might conflict with officially supplied packages.  Have you tried disabling those repositories and see if update works any better: `dnf --disablerepo=pgdg\* update`?  You seem to have `perl` available so I am not sure about the `perl` errors.

Comment: @GracefulRestart Updated question, `dnf --disablerepo=pgdg\* update` gives no error.
I'm pretty sure I installed `postgresql` after enabling `dnf module enable postgresql:12`, wondering how I should check that